# How to load window width value to SCSS variable?

Tags: variables, sass

I want to make an SCSS variable ($screensize) to have the value of current window width in px. How can I load that value into the variable? I want to use the value to calculate element size.

This is my SCSS code:

```
 input, label {
        $screensize: """window width in px"""
        
        $elementsize: strip-unit($screensize);
        transform: scale(calc(#{$elementsize}/50));}
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK, You need to rely on js for this. viewport width (100vw) is the only css solution I guess.

Comment: But how do you do that with JS?